# Exercise in algebra with modulo

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory

I'm studying Cassels' book *Elliptic Curves* for a week now, and I'm at the local global principle. I'm trying to prove the first exercise of this chapter, which says

> Let $p > 2$ be prime and let $b, c \in \Bbb Z$ and $ p $ does not divide $b$. Show that $bx^2 + c$ takes
>   precisely $\frac {p + 1}{2}$ distinct values $p$ for $x \in \Bbb Z$.

The problem here is that i don't understand what **"values $p$"** means. At first i thought that it means $\mod(p)$ values, but if that was the case, then for $x=0\in \Bbb Z$,we have that the $b\cdot 0^2+c=c$ can take $p-1$  values $\mod(p)$, $\{0,1,...,p-1\}$, and then we should have that $p-1=\frac {p + 1}{2}=>p=3$ which restricts the exercise.

So what  does **"values $p$"** mean?

Thank you!

Comment: No, $b$ and $C$ are given. You may only let run $x$ through the integers.

Comment: @DietrichBurde ,yeap,i got confused,but does values p mean modp values?

Comment: I think it must mean that.

Comment: It's likely the problem should read "$bx^2+c$ takes precisely $(p+1)/2$ distinct values mod $p$ for $x \in \mathbb{Z}.$" That is, the word "mod" should be inserted into the phrase immediately after the word "values" in the reading you have typed.

Comment: @coffeemath, by the way, do you have any idea how to start?

Comment: $x\rightarrow bx^2+c$ is a composition of three functions. Two are 1-1. The third isn't quite. Need more clues?

Comment: @user113576 I put up an "answer" which gives some outline, but would need a bit more work to write it up in a convincing form.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/799023/help-needed-in-understanding-proof-every-odd-prime-p-has-exactly-p-1-2-qu for the hard part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $b$ is not divisible by $p$ it has an inverse under multiplication, call it $b'$ for now, such that $b'b=1$ mod $p$. Then the equation $bx^2=c$ may be multiplied on both sides by $b'$ to get $b'bx^2=b'c,$ which since $b'b=1$ is the same as the equation
$$x^2=b'c \tag{1}$$
Thus since $b,c$ are fixed we may as well define $d=b'c$ and we're looking at the equation $x^2=d$. Now note that $x^2=(-x)^2$ for any $x$, and note that if $d \neq 0$ the values $x,-x$ are distinct, otherwise $2x=0$ and then $x=0$ since $p$ is odd. The solution to $x^2=0$ is only $x=0$, so that counts as one, and the other solutions can be paired up as $x,-x$ as indicated above. The "values taken on" are then the various possible $b$ which can appear on the right side of $x^2=b$, so by the 2-to-1 ness of the solutions for nonzero $b$ there are $(p-1)/2$ with nonzero $b$, and one more solution when $b=0$, for a total of $(p-1)/2+1=(p+1)/2.$

Once you've arrived at $x^2=b$ you are looking for values of $b$ which are either $0$ or else are what is called "quadratic residues". If you google the latter you can likely find sites where this count of the quadratic residues is done more carefully than outlined above.